# What is the debugging tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have [four questions](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging) tagged [debugging](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging).

- Two are *general* purpose "how can I perform debugging in this context?"
- Two are "what is the bug in this *specific* piece of code?"

Is it useful to have both types of question under the same tag, or would there be a benefit to using different tags? For example, perhaps [debugging](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging) for conceptual questions about debugging computer graphics code, and [broken-code](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-code) for how to fix a specific problem. A suggestion of a better name would be welcome. The tag wikis could then describe the usage.

Comment: I agree that [tag:debugging] should only be for conceptual questions, but I don't think we need a tag for broken code questions. Many questions with specific code will be about code that is broken somehow (doesn't work, too slow, needs too much memory, ...).